# Expected value and variance of the stock log-returns under Local Volatility framework

Tags: variance, local-volatility, log-returns, expected-value

I want to calculate the **expected value** and the **variance** of the stock process log-returns in the Local Volatility setting (and the realized/terminal correlation but let us begin in the one-dimentional setting). First some intro and my progress so far.

Consider the standard local volatility SDE:
$$
d S_t = \mu(t) S_t\, dt + \sigma(t,S_t) S_t dW_t
$$
with deterministic drift $\mu(t)$ and some deterministic local volatility function $\sigma(t,x)$. Using Ito's lemma we can derive the following SDE for the $\ln S_t$:
$$
d \ln S_t = \ln S_0 + \left( \mu(t) - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t,S_t)\right) dt  + \sigma(t, S_t)dW_t
$$
which can be written in the integral form as
$$ 
\ln S_t = \ln S_0 + \int_0^t \left( \mu(u) - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(u,S_u)\right) du + \int_0^t \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u
$$

I am interested in the log-returns over some (small) time interval $\Delta t$, thus, from the above we get
$$
\ln\left(\frac{S_{t+\Delta t}}{S_t}\right)
 = \ln(S_{t+\Delta t}) - \ln(S_{t}) = \\
= \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \left( \mu(u) - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(u,S_u)\right) du + \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \!\! \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u
$$

Proceeding to the quantities that I want to calculate, namely, the **expected value** and **variance**  of the **log-returns**, we have
$$ 
\mathbb{E}\left[ \ln\left(\frac{S_{t+\Delta t}}{S_t}\right) \right] =\\
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \left( \mu(u) - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(u,S_u)\right) du + \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \!\! \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u \right] = \\
=  \int_t^{t+\Delta t}  \mu(u) du
   - \frac{1}{2} \, \mathbb{E}  \left[ \int_t^{t+\Delta t} 
      \sigma^2(u,S_u) du\right]  
   + \mathbb{E}  \left[ \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \!\! \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u \right] 
$$
Since the last inegral is zero, we arrive at the following
\begin{eqnarray}\label{ev}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \ln\left(\frac{S_{t+\Delta t}}{S_t}\right) \right]
= \int_t^{t+\Delta t}  \mu(u) du
   - \frac{1}{2} \,  \int_t^{t+\Delta t} 
      \mathbb{E}  \left[ \sigma^2(u,S_u) \right] du  = \quad ... \,\, ???
\end{eqnarray}
Here is the place where I get stuck. **Question 1:** Is there a way to further simplify the second integral? It comes back in the variance derivation below, where I continue with this form of the expected value.

Further, the variance calculation goes as follows:
$$
\textrm{var} \left[ \ln\left(\frac{S_{t+\Delta t}}{S_t}\right) \right] =  \mathbb{E}\left[ \ln\left(\frac{S_{t+\Delta t}}{S_t}\right) - \mathbb{E}\left[ \ln\left(\frac{S_{t+\Delta t}}{S_t}\right) \right] \right]^2 = \\
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \left( \mu(u) - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(u,S_u)\right) du + \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \!\! \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u  \\ 
-  \int_t^{t+\Delta t}  \mu(u) du + \frac{1}{2} \,  \int_t^{t+\Delta t}  \mathbb{E}  \left[ \sigma^2(u,S_u) \right] du \right]^2 = \\
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \!\! \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u  -\frac{1}{2}  \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \left( \sigma^2(u,S_u) -  \mathbb{E}  \left[ \sigma^2(u,S_u) \right] \right) du \right]^2 = ...
$$
Now, we take the square and get the three components
$$ 
 ... = \mathbb{E}  \left[ \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \!\! \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u \right]^2 \\
 - \mathbb{E}  \left[ \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \!\! \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u 
\times 
 \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \left( \sigma^2(u,S_u) - \mathbb{E}  \left[ \sigma^2(u,S_u)\right]\right) du  \right] \\
+ \frac{1}{4} \, \mathbb{E}  \left[  \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \left( \sigma^2(u,S_u) - \mathbb{E}  \left[ \sigma^2(u,S_u)\right]\right) du \right]^2
$$

By virtue of the Ito's isometry the first component equals
$$
\mathbb{E}  \left[ \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \!\! \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u \right]^2 = \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \mathbb{E}  \left[ \sigma^2(u,S_u) \right] du
$$
which is the integral we have already seen in the expected value formula.
Thus, the whole variance of the log-return is (so far) given by
$$ 
 \textrm{var} \left[ \ln\left(\frac{S_{t+\Delta t}}{S_t}\right) \right]  = \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \mathbb{E}  \left[ \sigma^2(u,S_u) \right] du \\
 - \mathbb{E}  \left[ \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \!\! \sigma(u,S_u) dW_u 
\times 
 \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \left( \sigma^2(u,S_u) - \mathbb{E}  \left[ \sigma^2(u,S_u)\right]\right) du  \right] \\
+ \frac{1}{4} \, \mathbb{E}  \left[  \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \left( \sigma^2(u,S_u) - \mathbb{E}  \left[ \sigma^2(u,S_u)\right]\right) du \right]^2
$$

**Question 2:** In general, how to proceed further? Does the expected value of the product of the integrals simplify to something? Third component resembles the variance of the squared local volatility function - can we use it somehow?

Note that in case of constant volatility the variance of the log-return simplifies to $\sigma^2 \Delta t $, which is exactly what we define as volatility in the Black-Scholes setting. But I want to know what is the (empirical/realized) volatility in case of the Local Volatility model setting (as defined by the time scaled variance of the log-returns of the stock process).

Any advice/hint (also partial) would be appreciated!